# OCaml Reading from file and perform some validation

Tags: ocaml

can you help me out, i made this program to get an output from some .txt file like this :

john:3:uk
paul:18:us

```
#load "str.cma"
 
let f_test = "/home/test.txt" ;;

(*
  Recursive Reading function
 *)
let read_lines f_test : string list =
  if Sys.file_exists (f_test) then
    begin
      let ic = open_in f_test in
      try
        let try_read () =
          try Some (input_line ic) 
          with End_of_file -> None 
        in
        let rec loop acc = 
          match try_read () with
          | Some s -> loop (s :: acc)
          | None -> close_in_noerr ic; List.rev acc 
        in
        loop []
      with 
        e -> close_in_noerr ic; []
    end
  else
    []
 ;;
 
 (*Using Records*)
 type user = {
   name : string;
   age : int;
   country : string;
 };;
 
 (*
   Function to separated info in list
  *)
 let rec splitinfo ?(sep=":") l = 
   match l with
   | [] -> []
   | x::xs -> (Str.split (Str.regexp ":") x)::splitinfo xs;;

(*
  Function to get users position
 *)
let get_user l:user =
  let age = int_of_string (List.nth l 1) in
  let user_name = List.nth l 0 in
  {
    name = user_name;
    age = age ;
    country = List.nth l 2;
  };;

 (*
   Function to check some parameter is valid
  *)
 let par1 u: int =
   if (u.age = 3) then
     1
   else
     0;;

 (*
   Reporting function
  *)
 let report_statistics list_users =
   let child = ref 0 in
   let teenager = ref 0 in
   let adult = ref 0 in 
   print_string (" ----- -- Stats -- ----- \n" ) ;
   List.iter (
     fun user_l -> (
       match user_l with
       | [] -> print_string("> no user <\n")
       | _ ->
         let user = get_user user_l in
         if (par1 user = 1) then (
           print_string (" "^ user.name ^" --> Child \n" ) ;
           child := !child + 1;
         )
         else
           print_string (" "^ user.name ^" --> Other \n" );
     )
   ) list_users;
   print_string ("------- List ---- ");
   print_newline();
   print_string ("Child " );
   print_int(!child);
   print_newline();
   print_string ("Teenager ") ;
   print_int(!teenager);
   print_newline();
   print_string ("Adult ");
   print_int(!adult);
   print_newline();
 ;;
```

The program compile but doesn't output any result ...
What am i missing ?
I kept the function to check parameters simple so i can understand it better but can't figure it out why it isn't outputing any result

Can you help me out here ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The code as given defines some functions such as `read_lines` and `report_statistics`. But there are no calls to these functions.

If there is no other OCaml source involved, this is probably your problem. You need to call the functions.

It is fairly customary to have a "main" function that does the work of an OCaml program, and then (this is key) you have to actually call the main function:

```
let main () =
    (* Call the functions that do the work of the program *)

let () = main ()
```

I have many times forgotten this last line and then nothing happens when I run the program.

Comment: ```let main () =

   report_statistics list_users  

let () = main ()
;; ```

Comment: `let main =

let users_raw = read_lines f_utentes in
let list_users = splitinfo users_raw in
ignore(Sys.command "clear");
report_statistics list_users;;`

Comment: Now i'm getting , Fatal error: exception Failure("nth")

Comment: Take a look at where you call `List.nth`. You make the assumption that the list `l` will have at least two elements. If you try `List.nth [] 0` or `List.nth [2] 1` you'll get the same exception. So you may want to take a look at the input to your `get_user` function and make sure it's what you expect it to be.